# R cannot be resolved to a variable after so many tries

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am not sure why I am still having the `R` error. I have cleaned and rebuilt. I even have updated all my packages. Still the error.  I am having error at 3 places.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
findViewById(R.id.buttonSaveData)
findViewById(R.id.buttonLoadData)
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
    package com.sunil.externalstorage;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;



    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Environment;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

       EditText etData;
       Button btnSaveData, btnLoadData;

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         etData = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etData);
         btnSaveData = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSaveData);
         btnLoadData = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLoadData);

         // Writing data to internal storage
         btnSaveData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       if (isSDCardWritable()) {

          String dataToSave = etData.getText().toString();

          try {

           // SD Card Storage
           File sdCard =
                       Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
           File directory =
                       new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath()+"/MyFiles");
           directory.mkdirs();

                  File file = new File(directory, "text.txt");

           FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                  OutputStreamWriter osw =
                                        new OutputStreamWriter(fos);

           // write the string to the file
           osw.write(dataToSave);
           osw.flush();
           osw.close();

           // success message
           Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                       "File saved successfilly",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

           // clears the EditText
           etData.setText("");

          } catch (IOException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
        }

               } else {

           // SD Card Not Available
           Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                       "SD Card Not Available",
                         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }

         }
     });


       // Reading data from internal storage

       btnLoadData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub

          if (isSDCardReadable()) {

            try {

      // SD Card Storage
      File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
      File directory =
                     new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath()+ "/MyFiles");
      directory.mkdirs();
      File file = new File(directory, "text.txt");

      FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
             InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);

      char[] inputBuffer = new char[100];
             String dataToRead = "";
             int charRead;

      while ((charRead = isr.read(inputBuffer)) > 0) {
         String readString =
                       String.copyValueOf(inputBuffer,0, charRead);

         dataToRead += readString;
                inputBuffer = new char[100];
       }

     // set the EditText to the text that has been raed
     etData.setText(dataToRead);

     // success message
     Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                 "File loaded successfilly",
                              Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

          } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
     }

        } else {
           // SD Card Not Available
           Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SD Card Not Available",
                                   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       }
      }
           });

      }

      /* Checks if SD Card is available for read and write */
      public boolean isSDCardWritable() {
              String status = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
       if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(status)) {
      return true;
      }
       return false;
     }

    /* Checks if SD Card is available to at least read */
    public boolean isSDCardReadable() {
              String status = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
       if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(status)
    || Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(status)) {
      return true;
      }
     return false;
           }

    } 


    activity_main.xml


    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"  
        android:layout_height="match_parent"  
        tools:context=".MainActivity" >  

        <EditText  
            android:id="@+id/editText1"  
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"  
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"  
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"  
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"  
            android:ems="10" >  

            <requestFocus />  
        </EditText>  

        <EditText  
            android:id="@+id/editText2"  
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editText1"  
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"  
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"  
            android:ems="10" />  

        <TextView  
            android:id="@+id/textView1"  
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText1"  
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"  
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"  
            android:text="File Name:" />  

        <TextView  
            android:id="@+id/textView2"  
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText2"  
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText2"  
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"  
            android:text="Data:" />  

        <Button  
            android:id="@+id/button1"  
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText2"  
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"  
            android:layout_marginLeft="70dp"  
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"  
            android:text="save" />  

        <Button  
            android:id="@+id/button2"  
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"  
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"  
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button1"  
            android:text="read" />  

    </RelativeLayout>  


    AndroidManifest.xml


    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
    <manifest   

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
        package="com.sunil.externalstorage"  
        android:versionCode="1"  
        android:versionName="1.0" >  

        <uses-sdk  
            android:minSdkVersion="8"  
            android:targetSdkVersion="19" />  
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>  

        <application  
            android:allowBackup="true"  
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"  
            android:label="@string/app_name"  
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >  
            <activity  
                    `android:name="com.example.externalstorage.MainActivity"  
                android:label="@string/app_name" >  
                <intent-filter>  
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />  

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />  
                </intent-filter>  
            </activity>  
        </application>  

    </manifest>
```

Error log

[2015-01-01 21:07:18 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Parser exception for C:\Users\126327\Desktop\Year 3\Excelreader\AndroidManifest.xml: Element type "uses-permissionandroid:name" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
[2015-01-01 21:07:42 - Externalstorage] Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
[2015-01-01 21:07:42 - Externalstorage] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
[2015-01-01 21:07:42 - Externalstorage] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
[2015-01-01 21:07:42 - Externalstorage] Versions found are:
[2015-01-01 21:07:42 - Externalstorage] Path: C:\Users\126327\Desktop\Year 3\appcompat_v7\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2015-01-01 21:07:42 - Externalstorage]     Length: 987314
[2015-01-01 21:07:42 - Externalstorage]     SHA-1: 3b20dc871d179ba476082efe543dc1b38db46e30
[2015-01-01 21:07:42 - Externalstorage] Path: C:\Users\126327\Desktop\Year 3\Externalstorage\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2015-01-01 21:07:42 - Externalstorage]     Length: 995624
[2015-01-01 21:07:42 - Externalstorage]     SHA-1: 3e4e879d0b3dc11f2feb3f55e77e3b5bd82c4a28
[2015-01-01 21:07:42 - Externalstorage] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
[2015-01-01 21:07:42 - AndroidExternalStorage] Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
[2015-01-01 21:07:42 - AndroidExternalStorage] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
[2015-01-01 21:07:42 - AndroidExternalStorage] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
[2015-01-01 21:07:42 - AndroidExternalStorage] Versions found are:
[2015-01-01 21:07:42 - AndroidExternalStorage] Path: C:\Users\126327\Desktop\Year 3\appcompat_v7\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2015-01-01 21:07:42 - AndroidExternalStorage]  Length: 987314
[2015-01-01 21:07:42 - AndroidExternalStorage]  SHA-1: 3b20dc871d179ba476082efe543dc1b38db46e30
[2015-01-01 21:07:42 - AndroidExternalStorage] Path: C:\Users\126327\Desktop\Year 3\AndroidExternalStorage\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2015-01-01 21:07:42 - AndroidExternalStorage]  Length: 995624
[2015-01-01 21:07:42 - AndroidExternalStorage]  SHA-1: 3e4e879d0b3dc11f2feb3f55e77e3b5bd82c4a28
[2015-01-01 21:07:42 - AndroidExternalStorage] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
[2015-01-01 21:07:42 - AndroidExternalStorage] Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
[2015-01-01 21:07:42 - AndroidExternalStorage] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
[2015-01-01 21:07:42 - AndroidExternalStorage] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
[2015-01-01 21:07:42 - AndroidExternalStorage] Versions found are:
[2015-01-01 21:07:42 - AndroidExternalStorage] Path: C:\Users\126327\Desktop\Year 3\appcompat_v7\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2015-01-01 21:07:42 - AndroidExternalStorage]  Length: 987314
[2015-01-01 21:07:42 - AndroidExternalStorage]  SHA-1: 3b20dc871d179ba476082efe543dc1b38db46e30
[2015-01-01 21:07:42 - AndroidExternalStorage] Path: C:\Users\126327\Desktop\Year 3\AndroidExternalStorage\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2015-01-01 21:07:42 - AndroidExternalStorage]  Length: 995624
[2015-01-01 21:07:42 - AndroidExternalStorage]  SHA-1: 3e4e879d0b3dc11f2feb3f55e77e3b5bd82c4a28
[2015-01-01 21:07:42 - AndroidExternalStorage] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
[2015-01-01 21:07:42 - Externalstorage] Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
[2015-01-01 21:07:42 - Externalstorage] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
[2015-01-01 21:07:42 - Externalstorage] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
[2015-01-01 21:07:42 - Externalstorage] Versions found are:
[2015-01-01 21:07:42 - Externalstorage] Path: C:\Users\126327\Desktop\Year 3\appcompat_v7\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2015-01-01 21:07:42 - Externalstorage]     Length: 987314
[2015-01-01 21:07:42 - Externalstorage]     SHA-1: 3b20dc871d179ba476082efe543dc1b38db46e30
[2015-01-01 21:07:42 - Externalstorage] Path: C:\Users\126327\Desktop\Year 3\Externalstorage\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2015-01-01 21:07:42 - Externalstorage]     Length: 995624
[2015-01-01 21:07:42 - Externalstorage]     SHA-1: 3e4e879d0b3dc11f2feb3f55e77e3b5bd82c4a28
[2015-01-01 21:07:42 - Externalstorage] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
[2015-01-01 21:08:35 - Externalstorage] Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
[2015-01-01 21:08:35 - Externalstorage] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
[2015-01-01 21:08:35 - Externalstorage] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
[2015-01-01 21:08:35 - Externalstorage] Versions found are:
[2015-01-01 21:08:35 - Externalstorage] Path: C:\Users\126327\Desktop\Year 3\appcompat_v7\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2015-01-01 21:08:35 - Externalstorage]     Length: 987314
[2015-01-01 21:08:35 - Externalstorage]     SHA-1: 3b20dc871d179ba476082efe543dc1b38db46e30
[2015-01-01 21:08:35 - Externalstorage] Path: C:\Users\126327\Desktop\Year 3\Externalstorage\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2015-01-01 21:08:35 - Externalstorage]     Length: 995624
[2015-01-01 21:08:35 - Externalstorage]     SHA-1: 3e4e879d0b3dc11f2feb3f55e77e3b5bd82c4a28
[2015-01-01 21:08:35 - Externalstorage] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies
[2015-01-01 21:08:35 - AndroidExternalStorage] Found 2 versions of android-support-v4.jar in the dependency list,
[2015-01-01 21:08:35 - AndroidExternalStorage] but not all the versions are identical (check is based on SHA-1 only at this time).
[2015-01-01 21:08:35 - AndroidExternalStorage] All versions of the libraries must be the same at this time.
[2015-01-01 21:08:35 - AndroidExternalStorage] Versions found are:
[2015-01-01 21:08:35 - AndroidExternalStorage] Path: C:\Users\126327\Desktop\Year 3\appcompat_v7\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2015-01-01 21:08:35 - AndroidExternalStorage]  Length: 987314
[2015-01-01 21:08:35 - AndroidExternalStorage]  SHA-1: 3b20dc871d179ba476082efe543dc1b38db46e30
[2015-01-01 21:08:35 - AndroidExternalStorage] Path: C:\Users\126327\Desktop\Year 3\AndroidExternalStorage\libs\android-support-v4.jar
[2015-01-01 21:08:35 - AndroidExternalStorage]  Length: 995624
[2015-01-01 21:08:35 - AndroidExternalStorage]  SHA-1: 3e4e879d0b3dc11f2feb3f55e77e3b5bd82c4a28
[2015-01-01 21:08:35 - AndroidExternalStorage] Jar mismatch! Fix your dependencies

Comment: R has been deleted due to some error in your xml files. Or maybe you added some resource files with invalid file names. Try, **in this order**: Fix your errors. Do a Project/Clean, then Build. Restarting Eclipse wouldn't be a bad idea, too.

Comment: also make sure that you have `build-tools` installed in your `SDK` for your target API.

Answer (score 2):

The View names in your java files and your xml files do not match.

View names in your java files

```
etData = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etData);
     btnSaveData = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSaveData);
     btnLoadData = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonLoadData);
```

in XML files these views are not mentioned. Please change the names accordingly. It might work.

Comment: It still doesn't change Prem. The "R" is still underlined red.

Comment: @AppleCarrot did you try cleaning you project and re-making it?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't even read the error message, right?

The very beginning says,

> 2015-01-01 21:07:18 -
>   com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper]
>   Parser exception for C:\Users\126327\Desktop\Year
>   3\Excelreader\AndroidManifest.xml: Element type
>   "uses-permissionandroid:name" must be followed by either attribute
>   specifications, ">" or "/>".

So you have a syntax error in your AndroidManifest.xml

Looks like you have some other compilation errors too.

R is not resolved because it's generated at compile time, and the compile failed due to the reported errors. Fix the errors, and the compilation will complete, and R will be generated.